# How can I enable disabled layouts for Windows 8 touch keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-layout

[image]
The keyboard layout icons (lower right corner of this screenshot) from left to right: **QWERTY**, **Thumb** (split), **Handwriting**, and **Standard**.

There are several articles explaining how to enable the Standard (rightmost) layout, which apparently is disabled by default for many users. For me, that's the only keyboard layout I can access--Both the QWERTY and Thumb keyboards are disabled for me. I can use the handwriting "layout" but... who cares :P

How do I enable the disabled ones? My goal is to enable the leftmost one, QWERTY, which I think is the default on Windows 8 tablets.

I am running Windows 8.1 Pro on a MacBook Pro with Apple's Bootcamp drivers. No touch screen :D